# How to use icon as legend in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, bar-chart

There is a request to use icons to replace the legend:

[image]

So I need to change the country names in the legend to use each country's flag. Is there a way to do this in Chart.js? Or with any graph library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1554) on Chart.js github repo, however you can achieve your goal [extending](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html) draw function:

```js
var chartData = {
  "labels": ["Italy", "Germany", "Netherlands", "France", "Spain"],
  "datasets": [{
    "data": [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
    "fill": false,
    "backgroundColor": ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.5)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)"],
    "borderColor": ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
    "borderWidth": 1
  }]
};

for (var i in chartData.labels) {
  var lab = chartData.labels[i];
  var $img = $("<img/>").attr("id", lab).attr("src", "https://www.free-country-flags.com/countries/" + lab + "/1/tiny/" + lab + ".png");
  $("#pics").append($img);
}

var originalBarController = Chart.controllers.bar;
Chart.controllers.bar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
  draw: function() {
    originalBarController.prototype.draw.call(this, arguments);
    drawFlags(this);
  }
});

function drawFlags(t) {
  var chartInstance = t.chart;
  var dataset = chartInstance.config.data.datasets[0];
  var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(0);
  var y0 = chartInstance.scales.y0.top + chartInstance.scales.y0.height;
  ctx.save();
  meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
    var lab = bar._model.label;
    var img = document.getElementById(lab);
    ctx.drawImage(img, bar._model.x - 10, y0 - 6, 20, 12);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  ctx.restore();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": chartData,
  "options": {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    "scales": {
      "yAxes": [{
        id: "y0",
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#myChart {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

#pics {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200" width="400"></canvas>
<div id="pics"></div>
```

Here is also a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/0zderk1p/

Comment: Hi, i run the code, it doesn't give flag yet, still give the country name. can please recheck your snippet ?

Comment: I added also a jsfiddle to my answer

Comment: Have you tried both on SO and on jsfiddle? No errors in console log or network tab? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, tried both code snippet and JSFiddle. I ran safari and chrome with same result. something i miss ?

Comment: But if you open the script on jsfiddle, open Chrome network tab and click on "Run" you see all flag PNG pics downloaded with status 200?

Comment: Here is what you should see: https://imgur.com/a/WjUSo. And opening https://www.free-country-flags.com/countries/Italy/1/tiny/Italy.png you can see Italy flag?

Comment: Using another flag icon repo... https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/w658LLqL/ (icons from https://cdn2.iconfinder.com)